# Why the root of my stack in node.js + node-inspector is not the real root, I mean a function ran from an outrside source (like driver)

Tags: node.js, debugging, stack

I have a a debugger point in my code and I look in the call stack, I see about 11 lines deep but I cannot dig more. In the last level, the deeper one, is not a response from an async call like a driver nor an entry program, it's just some function called by another. But I cannot see that another function...

Any help how to see the other function?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try out https://github.com/CrabDude/trycatch and wrap some of your initial code with it.

```
var trycatch = require('trycatch')
trycatch(yourOriginalFunction, exceptionHandlerCallback)
```

It should give you a long stacktrace with your original function in it.

There are other libraries trying to solving this problem too but I haven't used them:

https://github.com/tlrobinson/long-stack-traces

https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn

Comment: interesting, you showed me even more than I wanted, I will test them tomorrow, thanks